# Unable to update column values in mysql using java?

Tags: java, mysql

I have created a table in mysql with one column "Sno". And inserted with 1 to 10 in column "Sno". I want to update columns values according to Sno, but am unable to do it. please help me. Thank you.

Here is what my code.

```
int o=2,q=0;
ResultSet rs = st7.executeQuery("select * from  table");
ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();//here is columns are added dynamically,So that is metadata is needed.

BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f1));//here f1 is csv file path.

while ((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {

    String[] splits = line1.split(",");//splitting line by ',' and storing into array.

    n1 = splits.length;

    for (m = 0; m < n1; m++) {

        st8.executeUpdate("UPDATE table SET " + metadata.getColumnName(o) + "='" + splits[m] + "' WHERE Sno='"+q+"'");
        o++;
    }

    q++;
    out.println("<br>");
}
```

Table structure

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+
|Sno     | col1   | col2   | col3   | col4    | col5      | 
+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+
| 0      |  NULL  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    |  NULL     |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+
| 1      | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL      |
```

Comment: What errors are you getting if any?

Comment: `table` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. Please use a different suitable name for your table.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
st8.executeUpdate("UPDATE `table` SET " + metadata.getColumnName(o) + "='" + splits[m] + "' WHERE Sno='"+q+"'");
```

since table is a reserved word.

You might have other problems, but this is certainly one that would break it.

And...you should really parameterize your query properly. It could also break because of inputs with single-quotes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query should be this

> "UPDATE table SET " + metadata.getColumnName(o) + "=" + splits[m] + " WHERE Sno="+q

just double-quote，no single quote.

hope it works